# Use of the word "register"

Tags: word-usage

Can the word "register" be used as in the following sentence? In the brackets is not a part of the sentence.

> The machine registers your name (on the machine itself).

I reviewed few dictionaries and seeing a very little possibility that this use is valid, but I just wanted to confirm here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

That is grammatically perfect. Google 'register definition' and im sure you will find that it fits like a glove :)

Edit: assuming you mean that the machine / computer will add the name to its internal repository for names, which can also be called a 'register'.

It is a verb in your example, and a noun in the above sentence.

Comment: Thank you! Dictionaries did not convince me on this because I could find example sentences only with the registering item or operating person as the nominative.